# datagridview 2 table wrong output

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Given the following code:

```
connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=consignacion.mdb;")
SQLStr = "Select buyer,balance,
         (SELECT SUM(salesdb.total)
          From salesdb
          Where salesdb.buyer = buyerdb.buyer and
                buydate=@buydate and
                salesdb.total is not Null and
                salesdb.total<>@sales ) As [paid]
                From buyerdb where balance>@balance"
cmd = New OleDbCommand(SQLStr, connection)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@buydate", Form1.Lbldate2.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance", 0)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sales", 0)
```

And below the ouput:

```
name    balance sales  
BANAL   1000      
BAYA    500   
RICKY   350   
GEN     0     
CASH    0     
BAGON   0     
LOREY   0     
TANIS   0       2250  
DARWIN  0       345  
GLEN    1000    4334  
LITO    0       505  
LIZA    0       460  
CESS    350     984  
LOUIE   0       280  
YOLLY   0       832  
GLENDA  0       170  
JOSE    1000    2240
```

I want to get the followed output:

```
name    balance     sales    
BANAL   1000      
BAYA    500   
RICKY   350   
TANIS   0           2250  
DARWIN  0           345  
GLEN    1000        4334  
LITO    0           505  
LIZA    0           460  
CESS    350         984  
LOUIE   0           280  
YOLLY   0           832  
GLENDA  0           170  
JOSE    1000        2240
```

i wanted to display all buyers with balance > 0
i wanted to display all buyer with sales/total >0 at a given date. (sometimes buyers dont have record of sales on a given date.
i don't want to display buyers with balance and sales/total is zero at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use an **`LEFT JOIN`** between `buyerdb b` and `salesdb s` on the `buyer` key, and perform a **`SUM()`** on these records according a **`GROUP BY`** command. It will display `buyerdb` rows (the left table) even if there are no corresponding `salesdb` rows:

```sql
SELECT b.buyer, b.balance, SUM(s.total) as total
FROM buyerdb b
LEFT JOIN salesdb s on (b.buyer = s.buyer AND s.buydate = @buydate)
GROUP BY buyer
```

Then, use this request as a **nested** one, and filtered to get only the rows you want:

```sql
SELECT t.buyer, t.balance, t.total 
FROM
(
  SELECT b.buyer, b.balance, SUM(s.total) as total
  FROM buyerdb b
  LEFT JOIN salesdb s on (b.buyer = s.buyer AND s.buydate = @buydate)
  GROUP BY buyer
) t
-- Filter the rows you don't want (both zero balance and total)
WHERE balance > 0 or total > 0
```

[Working SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f6b06/11) (should work with Access).

Comment: sorry for late reply, i had to check my database for problem also.
the actual output. is https://imgur.com/a/NgJphxF
i dont know why i am having this problem this is querying 2/11/2019

Comment: what if show all buyer with balance >0 then combine it with buyers with buyers with sales. group by buyer?

Comment: finally we made it!!!!
just edited this `GROUP BY buyer` into this `GROUP BY b.buyer,b.balance`

thank you very very very much!!!